# After logging in, the redirect does not work in CakePHP

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I have a cakephp website. After login the user should be redirected to a new page, this is working on local. But on dev site it is giving issues . 
When the user clicks on submit the URL of the next page gets appended to the current URL and the page is not redirecting.

This is the login function from Userscontroller

```php
   public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Recipes','action' => 'index']); 
                //return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
        }
    }
```

This is the initialize from AppController

```php
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
            'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
        ]);
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'email',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'loginAction' => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ],
            'storage' => 'Session',
             // If unauthorized, return them to page they were just on
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
        ]);

         //   $this->Auth->setConfig('authorize', ['Controller']);
        // Allow the display action so our PagesController
       // continues to work. Also enable the read only actions.
      /* $this->Auth->allow(['display', 'view', 'index','register','forgotPassword']);*/
        /*
         * Enable the following component for recommended CakePHP security settings.
         * see https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html
         */
        //$this->loadComponent('Security');
    }
```

I have also attached a screenshot of whats happening

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: PHP version i am using is  7.1.22

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. it seems the issues occurred because of cache as it is working on other computer . i cleared the cache it is working now.